# Hide arguments from error output on Yarn

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, devops, yarnpkg, circleci

I'm trying to deploy a Firebase project on CircleCI using Yarn and I'd like to prevent any environment variables from being displayed.

I'm using the `--silent` flag and it works fine during the deployment. However, when there's an error, Yarn outputs the command:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c firebase deploy --only functions,firestore --project staging --token my-token-is-being-displayed-here --non-inter
```

How can I prevent those arguments from being displayed in the error output? This is my current command:

```
yarn --silent deploy --project "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" --non-interactive
```